# django case sensitive url changes the case automatically

Tags: regex, django

I am using the following regex for my urls.

```
url(r'^p/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$',short_url, name='short_url')
```

and all urls are here :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
    url(r'^p/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$',short_url, name='short_url'),
    url('^accounts/register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=SimpleRegForm),
        name='registration_register'),
    # url(r'^accounts/edit/$', edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py file

```
def short_url(request, slug):
    ctx = {}
    ctx['post'] = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.select_related(),slug=slug)
    ctx['form'] = Form()
    return render(request, 'templates/view.html', ctx)
```

the URL is suppose to be case sensitive because I setup it that way in mysql for the slug field.

when I do mysql query it does exactly what it is suppose to be.

but when I change one letter like 'Y'

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/p/Y9j4oL/
```

to 'y' , django redirects to the above url again.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/p/y9j4oL/
```

why is this happening ? and how to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing built into Django that would do this. Show your full URLs and view.

Comment: code been updated

Comment: Is django actually receiving the uppercase URL? Are you testing this from a browser? They have a nasty tendency to replace what you're typing with what you've typed before...

Comment: I didn't know that browsers have this nasty behavior. when I tried with different browser it worked as intended.Safari didn't change the url to what I typed before, chrome did.  please post this as answer so I can mark it. thank you.